# barcode is not scannable

Tags: php, symfony, barcode, barcode-scanner

We are using paterik/BGBarcodeBundle bundle to generate barcode images(PNG) of package's tracking code.

However generated barcodes are not getting scanned by barcode scanner devices.
For reference, below is one image generated by paterik/BGBarcodeBundle bundle and another by some third party website. In both cases, "dipanjan" text is used for the input.

**Bundle:**

[image]

**Third party:**

[image]

You can notice there are differences in the generated barcodes (last three lines are more prominent). In both cases we have used C128B algorithm.

Can somebody please suggest how we can rectify this issue?

Comment: Check the font, width and sharpness of the barcode generated. A less sharp barcode having less width may result in overlaping lines leading to wrong interpretation by readers

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was the error with that bundle. However I have tried with "https://github.com/shangguokan/SGKBarcodeBundle" bundle and it worked for me :)